# Lookup Data if Date is greater than created date and within date range specified

Tags: excel, vba

I have an array formula which does what I want but it is very slow. Basically this formula gets the data from another sheet if date in my lookup sheet is greater than and within the date range.

Formula:

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$A$1:$B$9,MATCH(1,(Sheet2!B:B=B2)*(Sheet2!A:A>N2)*(Sheet2!A:A<N2+5),0),1),"Not yet released")}
```

Sample Image:

[image: This is a a sample file where the lookup value and formula is located]
Can VBA speed this up? or there is a much simpler way to do this?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps it can. Perhaps it can't. I won't go hunting for what you want by solving puzzles. Why don't you state what you want done in plain language?

Answer (score 0):

You can try by limiting the searched ranges, i.e. `Sheet2!B1:B9` instead of `Sheet2!B:B` (same for the other fields of the search) since your `INDEX`ed array is `A1:A9`.

```
INDEX(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$9,MATCH(1,(Sheet2!B1:B9=B2)*(Sheet2!A1:A9>N2)*(Sheet2!A1:A9<N2+5),0)),"Not yet released")}
```

In case the searched range grows, (say 100 lines instead of just 9), adjust the arrays in the formula accordingly, but dont make them unlimited like `A:A` because in case of no match found, Excel will keep searching until the row 1048576.